# Asp.net updatepanel , section of the page flickers

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have two link buttons inside an updatepanel. Problem is one section of the page flickers when either of the linkbuttons are clicked.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AjaxFrameworkMode="Enabled" />
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
           <li id="licc" runat="server" class="active">
              <asp:LinkButton ID="hlCC" runat="server" OnClick="hlCC_Click" PostBackUrl="#"><span class="number">1</span>Credit Card</asp:LinkButton></li>

       <li id="ligc" runat="server">
       <asp:LinkButton ID="hlGC" runat="server"  OnClick="hlGC_Click" PostBackUrl="#"><span class="number">2</span> Movie Gift Card</asp:LinkButton></li>
       </ul>
    </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There are no triggers. can sombody tell me why only one portion of the screen is flickering and not other portions?

thanks

Comment: That code fragment has issues.  You have a close tag on the content template inside the update panel.  Clean up the code first, then see about the flicker.

Comment: hi Gridly, that was a typo, actual code does not have problem. But the issue of flickering of a div in the page remains

Comment: Have you tried setting UpdateMode="Conditional" on the UpdatePanel?